# How to send notification to phone without play store (like huawei)

Tags: android, google-play, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

How to send notification to phone without play store installed (like Huawei). I know that Huawei use appGallery but how to send notification to those phones ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huawei does offer such a service. It's called HUAWEI Push Kit and is part of HUAWEI mobile services (HMS).
Documentation can be found here: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSPushKit/index.html#0

Also, I currently do not know about any service which abstracts from the push-backend. Firebase would be a candidate, but currently they only support APNS (Apple) and Google Push. So its up to the developer to support every individual push system.

Comment: these 2 providers seem to support HMS Push and abstract developers from push backend too; https://netmera.readme.io/docs/quick-start-4 and https://www.webinstats.com/blog/en/help/setup/#pushandroidconfig

Comment: Airship supports HMS Push now; https://docs.airship.com/platform/android/getting-started/#hms

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like `xmpp`, `websockets`, `gRPC` etc. but your app will need to be in the foreground to get messages from your server (or have a foreground service running). To be able to get push messages like you would from firebase you would need something that has system level permission and is excluded from Doze mode to be able to get push messages in the background. Somthing like that would have to come from the manufacturer.

Comment: I dont know but I would say probably not